# How to fade in a div when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My issue is that when I click on the button, the `div` container wouldn't fade in. Can anyone help?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stlye1.css">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <script>
    $("#header1").click(function () {
        $("#section_one").fadeIn('fast');
    });
    </script>
    
    <body>
        <button type="button"  id="header1">div 1</button>
        <div id="section_one" class="parallax1">
            <div>
                <h1>text</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't tell the div to hide with the style="display: none".

There is you code back

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stlye1.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" id="btn1">div 1</button>

        <div id="div1" class="parallax1" style="display: none">
            <div>
                <h1>text</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            $("#div1").fadeIn("fast");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: actually i did this is code from css 
.parallax1 {
    display: none;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:red;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 33px;
}

Comment: What is the name of your css file ? Because you named it stlye1.css in your html head instead of style1.css. You can also see those errors in your F12 console in your browser

Comment: css file was fine it was script problem your jquery code make it work thanks.